# JQuery difference between searching 'children' and 'find'?

Tags: jquery

When is one preferred over the other when searching for nested Divs?

Comment: Prefer this link also for better understanding http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Find is recursive, where children looks only 1 level deep in the DOM. Check out this: http://blog.ekini.net/2009/03/16/jquery-children-vs-find-which-is-faster/

Note: that is actually references a Stackoverflow post.

Either way, that should help answer your question. If you need to search more than one level use Find, if not use children as it is faster.

Answer (score 11):

> *The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.*

Source: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

**find() vs childern() in jQuery**

> find() – search through the matched elements in all the subsequent
>   level ,All levels down.
>
> children() – search through the matched elements’ child only (single
>   level down).