# My code is working and the first line is displaying correctly but the second line is concatenated with the first line etc

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr.item").each(function () {
            var weight = $(this).children('td.Weight').text();
            var unit = "Kg";
            $(".Weight").text(weight + unit);

            });


    });
</script>
 html code...
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr class="item">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderQty)
    </td>
    <td class="Weight">
        @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.TotalWeight, new { id="TotalWeight"})
    </td>
  </tr>
```

the values keep on concatenating with themseleves for eg: 5000Kg,then 5000KgKg, then 5000KgKgKg and so on..I'm not able to take the current value in consideration, the code considers all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector used at `$(".Weight").text(weight + unit);` selects all elements with the class "Weight" and not just the ones within the current `tr` element. You do find the correct element by using `$(this).children("td.Weight")` though so just reuse that one.

```
$("tr.item").each(function () {
  var $weight = $(this).children(".weight"),
      weight = $weight.text(),
      unit = "Kg";

  $weight.text(weight + unit);
});
```

BTW: I´d recommend you to use shorter selectors, in this case `.Weight` is enough and to be consistent with the class names (make "Weight" lowercase).

Comment: +1 for saving the element into a variable and not searching for it again! :)

Comment: Instead of using children, you should consider using the faster find which also will keep being valid if the .Weight comes to be a span and not directly the TD. You can also use `$('.Weight', this)` (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$(".Weight").text(weight + unit);
```

to

```
$(".Weight", this).text(weight + unit);
```

so that only the `.Weight` cell of the current row is changed.

A prevision following comments :

- it's useless to cache selectors here, there wouldn't be any noticeable gain and it makes the code harder to read and maintain
- using `children` is slower, which isn't very important. What's important is that using `children` departs from the semantic use of classes, it makes your code rely on the fact the `.Weight` element is a direct child and not, for example a `span` in a `td`. That's exactly the same reason than why you should generally prefer `closest` over `parent`.

Comment: what is the difference between your approach and this one `$(this).find('weight').text (....)` ?

Comment: @dreamweiver it's basically the same. It's just more direct.

Comment: But i found out here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384793/jquery-difference-between-searching-children-and-find , that `.children()` is best suited for 1 level dom search whereas `.find()` is suited for nested level dom search. in this scenario  i guess `.children()` would be best

Comment: -1 your code would end up uselessly forcing the browser to find `.Weight` twice...

Comment: I see no gain in using `children`. This adds one more constraint (the element being a direct child) that will have to change when the HTML changes. When you have classes or id, it's better to use them only instead of presupposing the structure.

Comment: @dystroy why is that?

Comment: @Venemo why would it?

Comment: Do you have an idea of the code of this search ? Can you really think it's worth making the code more complex and verbose ? BTW this really is a detail, there's no point in rewriting OP's code when he's asking why his code doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @dreamweiver Just a complement : $('.Weight', this) is much faster than find and of course than children : http://jsperf.com/findorjustjquery

Comment: @dystroy the truth is, I always cache my selectors. I don't think it's a reason for downvote not to, however.

Comment: Well, if you cache the selector to avoid a second search but use a slow function like children, you're losing both in perfs and in readibility...

Comment: Wow , thats amazing. no wonder you have 89k rep :) nice job man

Comment: @Nasreen ** Sir,thanks for your reply, but in the code u have mentioned me to use 'this' but the context of this there is limited to tr and not to td..So the first line of result is fine but in the second line the value of 5000 is not there only Kg is shown.**

Comment: Sir give me fiddle example consisting of five lines of data having values concatenated with unit.